# read from properties file name of javascript buttons

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to read name of button from .properties file? When I do like this it doesn't work(it's javascript on .jsp page between `<script>` tags).

```
 $("#dialog-form")  
            .dialog(  
                    {  
                        autoOpen : false,  
                        dialogClass : "texter",  
                        height : 410,  
                        width : 350,  
                        modal : true,  
                        buttons : {  
                            "${book}" : function() {  
                                var bvalid = true;  
                                allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");  
                                bvalid = bvalid && checkNumber(apart);  
                                bvalid = bvalid && checkNumber(beds);  
                                bvalid = bvalid && checkNumber(days);  
                                if (bvalid) {  
                                    $("#dialog-form").submit();  
                                    $(this).dialog("close");  
                                }  
                            },  
                            "${not}" : function() {  
                                $(this).dialog("close");  
                            }  
                        },  
                        close : function() {  
                            allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");  
                        },  
                        open : function() {  
                            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find(  
                                    'button:contains("${book}")').addClass(  
                                    'texter');  
                            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find(  
                                    'button:contains("${not}")').addClass(  
                                    'texter');  
                        }  
                    });
```

Comment: What do you mean with *it doesn't work*? Is there another way you tried that works?

Comment: Well I tried without `""` at all